# Google Sheets - Can't find what's wrong with my Query function based on Today() function

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I've gone through the many similar questions for the past two days and can't seem to find what's not working.

My function is:

```
=IFNA(QUERY(A2:I,"select B,C where F = date '"&text(today(),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'",1),"")
```

Where I'm trying to query all the first+last names in columns B, C if their corresponding date in F is today.

But instead, it just queries the entire columns, regardless of the corresponding dates.

It's so annoying, please help me fix the function :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want first & last names in **different column**

Try this: `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(IF(C1:C=TODAY(),A1:A&" "&B1:B,"")," ")))`

For you range: `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(IF(F2:F=TODAY(),B2:B&" "&C2:C,"")," ")))`

[image: result]

If you want first & last name in **same cell**

Try this: `=ArrayFormula(IF(F2:F=TODAY(),B2:B&" "&C2:C,""))`

[Arrayformula()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

[If function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)